# Как сверстать svg

Tags: svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста сверстать свгэшечку)

Comment: это часть окружности и 3 линии, с чем у Вас сложности?

Comment: В крайнем случае всегда можно открыть Adobe Illustrator или Inkscape и нарисовать всё в нём

Comment: Причем тут ReactJS ???

Answer (score 3):

Написано руками

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200">
  <defs>
    <style>
      circle{
        transform-origin: center;
        transform: rotate(-90deg)
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="10" fill="transparent" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="40 70" />
  <g transform="translate(5,0)scale(.6)">
    <path d="M25,43 30,38 20,38z" fill="#000"/>
    <line x1="25" x2="25" y1="25" y2="38" stroke="#000"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

Нате!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="58px" height="87px" viewBox="0 0 58 87" enable-background="new 0 0 58 87" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="58" height="87" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADoAAABXCAYAAABV0VasAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN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" />
</svg>
```